# How to read the first byte of HAL_UART_Receive?

Tags: c++, stm32, esp32

I'm trying to send a single char ("A") to my STM32 from my ESP32. I can see that the char goes through as I am receiving the char back on the ESP32 in the Arduino serial monitor but I can't seem to understand how to access it for using it to do something else on the STM32. Here is what I've been trying...

```
//STM32 Code:
uint8_t RxTx_1[100];
while (1)
{
/* USER CODE END WHILE */


  HAL_UART_Receive(&huart1, (uint8_t*)RxTx_1, sizeof(RxTx_1), 100); // Receive comms from ESP32

  if (RxTx_1[0] = "A"){
      HAL_GPIO_TogglePin(GPIOA, GPIO_PIN_5); // Blink
      HAL_Delay(1000);
  }
  
  HAL_Delay(1000);
  HAL_UART_Transmit(&huart1, (uint8_t*)RxTx_1, sizeof(RxTx_1), 100);


/* USER CODE BEGIN 3 */
}
/* USER CODE END 3 */
}
```

I know its got to be something simple but I can't seem to find anything online about how to do it.

Comment: `if (RxTx_1[0] = "A"){` should be `if (RxTx_1[0] == 'A'){`

Comment: I'm so sorry, it appears I did not initialize the LED I was using to debug this as I had already tried that. Thank you anyway!

Comment: Your compiler probably told you something like "warning: comparison between pointer and integer" and you ignored that. Please don't do that. In fact, please add -Werror to your compiler flags, so you can't ignore it in future.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To expand on the comment from @πάντα ῥεῖ:

`"A"` is a string literal, with a type of `const char[N]`. This particular one is the string/array `{'A', '\0'}` (remember the terminating null-character). So `if (RxTx_1[0] = "A")` compares your Rx `char` to a pointer.

`'A'` is the character `A` with a `char` type, and `if (RxTx_1[0] == 'A')` does what you want.